# how to manage django formsets

Tags: python, django, forms, model

i am using django formset models with three dropdowns  from another table`ForeingKey`with `extra=3`lines so i have form like this
[form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqXjy.png)
i need formset management that Automatically chooses first dropdwon for the first formsetline and the second  for the second like this[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhHlK.png)
**i tried this**

```
def create_order(request,):
    orderformset = modelformset_factory(order, form=orderForm,extra=3)
    queryset = order.objects.none()
    formset = orderformset(request.POST or None,queryset=queryset)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()

        return redirect('home')
```